# Symfony BrowserKit link com acentuação gráfica não clica

Tags: php, symfony

Estou estudando crawler com php symfony e me deparei com a seguinte situação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O link funciona sem acento mas quando o link tem acento simplesmente não clica no link.
Já verifiquei charset na app php, site e da ide vscode todos batem. UTF-8
Se alguém tiver uma ideia de como resolver isso eu agradeço.

Fiz uma alteração no script na tentativa de resolver esse caso.

```
$link = $crawler->filter('.menu-item')->eq(2);
$crawler = $browser->clickLink($link);
$link = $linkCrawler->link();
```

Recebi o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tudo na vida é questão de paciência e determinação.
Não sou expert no assunto e tão pouco conhecia Symfony para crawler.
Após muitas tentativas cheguei a um resultado que seja satisfatório.
Finalmente consegui clicar no link que contém acentos.
Claro que tive ajuda de um colega programador "desconhecido".
https://jciel.github.io/2019/PHP-web-crawler-com-dom-crawler-component-do-symfony/
Ele me deu uma dica e em cima da dica dele cheguei no código que executa um clique em um link que contém acentuação:

```
$link = $crawler->filter('.menu-item')->eq(2)->link();
$crawler = $browser->click($link);
$html = $crawler->html();
echo $html;
```

Ficou show de bola.
E com isso nem precisei alterar encoding.
Se é culpa dos janelas?
Penso que não é apenas ajustes no código para contornar um obstáculo.
Pessoas são pessoas códigos são códigos.
Para as pessoas eu tenho um conselho:
Não julgue a outra por apenas fazer uso da camiseta de cor azul.
E jogar o problema na cor.
Agora para o código digo que tem várias maneiras de se comer um Tostines.
Eu apenas estou comendo de uma outra forma.
Apresentei um problema e muitos ficaram focados na cor da minha camisa.
Mas enfim vida que segue.